# HTML Javascript | how to get a value of a links array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small html code base that produces a list of unique links, I want to get each an every link's text value using java script (not the link only the text).

my sample code (doesn't work)

```
for (var x = 0; x < document.getElementById("folderLink").length; x++) {
       alert(document.getElementById("folderLink")[x].innerHtml);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="folderLink" href="somelink">Dynamic Text Text Text</a>
```

assume that this is a one link of the list.

Thanks.

Comment: That *example* link doesn't have any text in, and it's invalid (`/>`...)

Comment: And "innerHtml" should be spelt "innerHTML"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` will only ever return one element, regardless of how many there may be with that ID. Because there *should*  only ever be one element of any ID.

So you can't access its `length` because it's not a collection it's a DOM node.

You could use `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @MMRUser: well, you have to make sure that the links *have* that class, to be able to access them by it. also, as others have pointed out, it should be `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`, and your example link *does not have* an inner html.